# CentOS7 - DNS register only succeeds every third time

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain, centos7

I have a CentOS 7.2 installation used for VDI, which is joined automatically into Microsoft 2008 R2 Domain (DCs are 2012 R2) at provisioning by using a bash script. AD join with the command `"net ads join -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'`" is successful (verified with "`net ads testjoin`", "`net ads info`" and "`wbinfo -u`"). DNS registration is unsuccessful.
The DNS registration directly during the join fails with "`DNS update failed!`".
Registering the linux manually using "`net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'`" succeeds only every third time:

```
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'                                                                                                                                                       DNS Update for vw-centos7-001.lab.mycompany.ch failed: ERROR_DNS_UPDATE_FAILED
DNS update failed!
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
DNS Update for vw-centos7-001.lab.mycompany.ch failed: ERROR_DNS_GSS_ERROR
DNS update failed!
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
Successfully registered hostname with DNS
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
DNS Update for vw-centos7-001.lab.mycompany.ch failed: ERROR_DNS_UPDATE_FAILED
DNS update failed!
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
DNS Update for vw-centos7-001.lab.mycompany.ch failed: ERROR_DNS_GSS_ERROR
DNS update failed!
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
Successfully registered hostname with DNS
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
DNS Update for vw-centos7-001.lab.mycompany.ch failed: ERROR_DNS_UPDATE_FAILED
DNS update failed!
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
DNS Update for vw-centos7-001.lab.mycompany.ch failed: ERROR_DNS_GSS_ERROR
DNS update failed!
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
Successfully registered hostname with DNS
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
DNS Update for vw-centos7-001.lab.mycompany.ch failed: ERROR_DNS_UPDATE_FAILED
DNS update failed!
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
DNS Update for vw-centos7-001.lab.mycompany.ch failed: ERROR_DNS_GSS_ERROR
DNS update failed!
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
Successfully registered hostname with DNS
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
DNS Update for vw-centos7-001.lab.mycompany.ch failed: ERROR_DNS_UPDATE_FAILED
DNS update failed!
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
DNS Update for vw-centos7-001.lab.mycompany.ch failed: ERROR_DNS_GSS_ERROR
DNS update failed!
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]# net ads dns register -U 'Administrator%Passw0rd'
Successfully registered hostname with DNS
[root@vW-CentOS7-001 administrator]#
```

The issues persists if I define a specific domain controller (`-S`) when running "`net ads dns register`" as well as master_kdc in `krb5.conf`.
There is nothing regarding dns or register in the Samba log files (" `egrep -iR 'dns|register' /var/log/samba/`").
Why does it fails two out of three times?
What do I have to do that I do not need to register it three times in my script?

Comment: CentOS 7.7? 7.2.1511 is the latest available at this time.

Comment: @JasonAzze: Yes, you're right, sorry. Corrected the error. It is 7.2.1511.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have multiple DNS servers configured

Add `DHCP_HOSTNAME=<hostname_of_machine>` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file (if the interface is in fact eth0).

Run `service network restart`.

Run `net ads join -U administrator` command.

Also;
In the /etc/hosts file can you confirm the 127.0.0.1 entry has your intended hostname.. for example 127.0.0.1 mymachine.mycompany.com mymachine

Comment: I tried with DHCP_HOSTNAME=`hostname` as well as DHCP_HOSTNAME=`hostname -s`. Issue still persists. Btw: when I run the "net ads join" command three times in a row, I have the same behaviour (join works, but DNS only works every third time).

Comment: Update: same issue if I use directly the hostename (DHCP_HOSTNAME="vW-CentOS7-001") instead of DHCP_HOSTNAME=\`hostname\` resp. \`hostname -s\`

Comment: @HBruijn.. thanks,new enough here @NoBodyIsPerfect .. something to confirm, or add : in the `/etc/hosts` file can you confirm the 127.0.0.1 entry has your intended hostname.. for example `127.0.0.1 mymachine.mycompany.com mymachine` this comes from quote:"This is a problem with the client identity. Please edit /etc/hostname with
the short name, also edit /etc/hosts with the fully qualified domain name of
the machine. Since we have a disjoined DNS space for our AD, I put a line
like the following in my /etc/hosts file" from http://www.mail-archive.com/samba@lists.samba.org/msg101228.html

Comment: Not only is this wrong (127.0.0.1 should be named localhost, not your external machine name), it also doesn't fix the problem for me.

Comment: Well, if its not about its own name resolution, how about the domain membership on the Active Directory side? Reading on mailing lists there seems to be a number of people resolving this issue by querying the AD server with samba-tool to confirm the DNS record is resolving correctly and correcting is required.  `samba-tool dns query <DC FQDN> <DNS Domain> <Member Server FQDN> A
-U Administrator --password=<your AD Administrator
password>` and `samba-tool dns add <DC FQDN> <DNS Domain> <Member Server FQDN> A
<IPaddress> -U Administrator --password=<your AD Administrator
password>`